# How to force UITextView to recognize three digit phone number

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview

I have a view with a `UITextView` element. Using the Interface Builder, I set the `dataDetectorTypes` property to `UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber` to make it recognize phone numbers. It works for regular numbers, but not for very short ones, e.g. 911 or it's european equivalent 112.

Is it possible to somehow force UITextView to recognize these numbers just like the long ones?

Comment: Maybe they did that on purpose, so you don't press "911" accidentally.

Comment: There is a way but it would involve you subclassing or using categories to implement your own method that does the same thing. I would think that this would be a difficult task as no the potential for any number sequence of 3 numbers would be flagged. You could wrap you html in some custom text and use that to flag a number but then again that would be limiting yourself to pages you have built ...